# Prevent Python Interpreter from Exiting if CTRL-D is pressed

Tags: python, linux, python-internals

I am running a script with `python -i main.py`. The script starts some C threads and python threads using `threading` module, then python code ends and it goes to a prompt. How can i prevent python from exiting if CTRL-D is accidentally pressed? I don't want to press CTRL-D by accident (already happened twice) and suddenly the interactive interpreter is down with all its threads.

I need the to still have access to the interactive interpreter. The goal is to start the C threads and python threads, then monitor them later from python.

I tried using `readline` and binding ^D to nothing, but it would still terminate python.

Example (main.py):

```
print("Init code for python thread")
print("Init code for c thread")
```

When running this with `python -i main.py`, after the second line is finished, i get the prompt `>>>`. If i am at the prompt and press CTRL-D, it will start a systemExit. I want to prevent that at all costs.

Comment: What is you python code? Why do you press ^D in the first place? What kind of prompt do you land in?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], namely code that exits when Control-D is pressed.

Comment: Oh, you want to disable Control-D from exiting the *interactive* interpreter.

Comment: `ipython`, at least, is configured to prompt you before exiting in this situation. I don't recall what, if any, option is available to configure the Readline library used by the regular Python interpreter to do the same.

Comment: yes, exactly, i want to disable Control-D from exiting the interactive interpreter.

Comment: provided a minimal example

Answer (score 1):

If you are waiting on input then you can wrap the input call in try/except. Remember that Ctrl-D is effectively EOF.

Therefore this might be a useful pattern:

```
while True:
    try:
        v = input('Type something: ')
        break
    except EOFError:
        print('You typed CTRL-D')

print(f'You typed {v}')
```